# VB.NET WebBrowser shows iframe code as text

Tags: vb.net, iframe, webbrowser-control

So I'm inside a complex webbrowser project, and when loging in a specific site (www.habbo.es) the webbrowser won't load the iframe that has the main content, but rather display it as text.

[image: Habbo as seen through the webbrowser]

When I do the same in IE it works perfectly.

Why does this happen at all?

If you need any further information just ask for it.

Comment: looks like some bot protection. you could try to usw selenium to control an firefox/IE instance. Or replace your IE Webbrowser Componente with an FF Component.

Comment: It might be. Thanks a lot, I'll try your suggestion.